# OCaml: parse minus floating-point number as a calculator

Tags: parsing, ocaml, programming-languages

## What I would like to do

I would like to correctly parse minus floating-point numbers.

How should I fix my code?

## What is not working

When I try to interpret `- 5` as `-5.000000`, it shows me this error.

```
Fatal error: exception Stdlib.Parsing.Parse_error
1c1
< error: parse error at char=0, near token '-'
---
> - 5 = -5.000000
```

## My source code

### calc_ast.ml

```ml
(* abstract syntax tree *)
type expr =
  Num of float
| Plus of expr * expr
| Times of expr * expr
| Div of expr * expr
| Minus of expr * expr
;;
```

### calc_lex.ml

```ml
{
open Calc_parse
;;
}

rule lex = parse
| [' ' '\t' '\n' ]               { lex lexbuf }
| '-'? ['0' - '9']+ as s    { NUM(float_of_string s) }
| '-'? ['0' - '9']+ ('.' digit*)? as s   { NUM(float_of_string s) }
| '+'                 { PLUS }
| '-'                 { MINUS }
| '*'                 { TIMES }
| '/'                 { DIV }
| '('                 { LPAREN }
| ')'                 { RPAREN }
| eof                 { EOF }
```

### calc_parse.mly

```ml
%{
%}

%token <float> NUM
%token PLUS TIMES EOF MINUS DIV LPAREN RPAREN

%start program
%type <Calc_ast.expr> program

%%

program :
 | compound_expr EOF       { $1 }

compound_expr :
  | expr               { $1 }
  | LPAREN expr RPAREN { $2 }

expr :
 | mul             { $1 }
 | expr PLUS mul   { Calc_ast.Plus($1, $3) }
 | expr MINUS mul  { Calc_ast.Minus($1, $3) }

mul :
 | NUM             { Calc_ast.Num $1 }
 | mul TIMES NUM   { Calc_ast.Times($1, Calc_ast.Num $3) }
 | mul DIV NUM     { Calc_ast.Div($1, Calc_ast.Num $3) }

%%
```

### calc.ml

```ml
open Calc_parse

(* token -> string *)
let string_of_token t =
  match t with
    NUM(s) -> Printf.sprintf "NUM(%f)" s
  | PLUS   -> "PLUS"
  | TIMES  -> "TIMES"
  | MINUS  -> "MINUS"
  | DIV    -> "DIV"
  | LPAREN -> "LPAREN"
  | RPAREN -> "RPAREN"
  | EOF    -> "EOF"
;;

(* print token t and return it *)
let print_token t =
  Printf.printf "%s\n" (string_of_token t);
  t
;;

(* apply lexer to string s *)
let lex_string s =
  let rec loop b = 
    match print_token (Calc_lex.lex b) with
      EOF -> ()
    | _ -> loop b
  in
  loop (Lexing.from_string s)
;;

(* apply parser to string s; 
   show some info when a parse error happens *)
let parse_string s = 
  let b = Lexing.from_string s in
  try
    program Calc_lex.lex b      (* main work *)
  with Parsing.Parse_error as exn ->
    (* handle parse error *)
    let c0 = Lexing.lexeme_start b in
    let c1 = Lexing.lexeme_end b in
    Printf.fprintf stdout
      "error: parse error at char=%d, near token '%s'\n" 
      c0 (String.sub s c0 (c1 - c0));
    raise exn
;;

(* evaluate expression (AST tree) *)
let rec eval_expr e =
  match e with
    Calc_ast.Num(c) -> c
  | Calc_ast.Plus(e0, e1)
    -> (eval_expr e0) +. (eval_expr e1)
  | Calc_ast.Minus(e0, e1)
    -> (eval_expr e0) -. (eval_expr e1)
  | Calc_ast.Times(e0, e1)
    -> (eval_expr e0) *. (eval_expr e1)
  | Calc_ast.Div(e0, e1)
    -> (eval_expr e0) /. (eval_expr e1)
;;

(* evaluate string *)
let eval_string s =
  let e = parse_string s in
  eval_expr e
;;

(* evaluate string and print it *)
let eval_print_string s =
  let y = eval_string s in
  Printf.printf "%s = %f\n" s y
;;

let eval_print_stdin () =
  let ch = stdin in
  let s = input_line ch in
  eval_print_string (String.trim s)
;;

let main argv =
  eval_print_stdin ()
;;

if not !Sys.interactive then
  main Sys.argv
;;
```

Comment: Your lex rule will not accept a space between the `-` and the `5`, so you end up with two tokens instead of one.

Comment: I suggest you treat negative numbers as a parsing problem rather than a scanning problem. Remove the lexical rules for negative numbers and add `NEG NUM` as an alternate rule for `mul` in your parser. This is the usual handling, I think. E.g., you can have a comment between the `-` and the number in most languages.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in the comments, it's almost never a good idea for the lexical analyser to try to recognise the `-` as part of a numeric literal:

- Since the lexical token must be a contiguous string, `- 5` will not match. Instead, you'll get two tokens. So you need to handle that in the parser anyway.
- On the other hand, if you don't put a space after the `-`, then `3-4` will be analysed as the two tokens `3` and `-4`, which is also going to lead to a syntax error.

A simple solution is to add `term` to recognise the unary negation operator:

```
mul :
 | term               { Calc_ast.Num $1 }
 | mul TIMES term     { Calc_ast.Times($1, Calc_ast.Num $3) }
 | mul DIV term       { Calc_ast.Div($1, Calc_ast.Num $3) }
term :
 | NUM                { $1 }
 | MINUS term         { Calc_ast.Minus(0, $2) }
 | LPAREN expr RPAREN { $2 }
```

In the above, I also moved the handling of parentheses from the bottom to the top of the hierarchy, in order to make `4*(5+3)` possible. With that change, you will no longer require `compound_expr`.